# Sampling without replacement over multiple samples

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table in Oracle, let's say with 99 rows. I want to take three different (random) samples from the table, making sure it's without replacement *between* the three different samples. This is to say, sample_1 may contain rows 1-33, sample_2 may contain rows 34-66, and sample_3 may contain rows 67-99. I do **not** want samples where there is overlap between the rows, i.e. sample_1 contains rows 1-33, sample_2 contains rows 21-53, etc...

The code I have so far is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE training_sample_1 AS
SELECT *
FROM pmaster_numeric
SAMPLE BLOCK (33, 100)
```

I am using SAMPLE BLOCK because my table is actually ~ 10 million rows long, and a seed value because I want to be able to reference this sample in the future. Again, I want to make two more samples - training_sample_2 and test_sample_1 - of the same size, *making sure none of the three sample tables contain rows that are also in other sample tables* (without replacement).

Comment: Are your three samples going to comprise the entire data set as in your example?  Or are you really going to take three very small samples such that the vast majority of the rows will not be in any sample?  Do the three samples need to be exactly the same size?  Or is it sufficient for them to be in roughly the same size (i.e. one that is 3.30 million rows, one with 3.38 million rows, one with 3.32 million rows) ?

Comment: Hi @JustinCave, yes, the three samples are indeed going to comprise the entire data set (why not use all the data I have available? I am running regressions / classification trees and want as much significance as possible). The three samples don't necessarily have to be the exact same size, as long as they're comparable. I think I solved my own question (see answer below), but I would love to see where you are going with your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(EDITED)

Here's the SQL I ended up using:

```
-- Create randomly-ordered pmaster_numeric table
CREATE TABLE random_order_pmaster_numeric AS 
SELECT pmast.*, dbms_random.value AS row_number
FROM pmaster_numeric pmast
ORDER BY dbms_random.value;

-- training_sample_1
CREATE TABLE training_sample_1 AS
SELECT *
FROM random_order_pmaster_numeric 
WHERE row_number > 0 and row_number <= .3;

-- training_sample_2
CREATE TABLE training_sample_2 AS
SELECT *
FROM random_order_pmaster_numeric 
WHERE row_number > .3 and row_number <= .6;

-- training_sample_3
CREATE TABLE training_sample_3 AS
SELECT *
FROM random_order_pmaster_numeric 
WHERE row_number > .6 and row_number <= .9;

-- test_sample_1
CREATE TABLE test_sample_1 AS
SELECT *
FROM random_order_pmaster_numeric 
WHERE row_number > .9;
```

What I am doing here is randomly ordering my entire table, keeping the dbms_random.value (after noticing there's a uniform distribution of values over the interval 0-1) then breaking it up into equi-sized (in terms of # of rows) pieces, which I then designate as my samples. This avoids replacement because I am choosing the row selections instead of the SAMPLE BLOCK clause, and making sure that there is no row overlap between sample tables (the WHERE clauses in my queries).

Here, the training samples are all 3X as large as the test sample.

Comment: The second two queries will not return any rows.  There is no guarantee that rows will be returned in any particular order as well so there is no guarantee that the first row will return the same set of data if you run it multiple times.

Comment: I see your point...I had only tried the first sample when I posted this. Thanks again, @JustinCave. Very helpful.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why don't the second two queries return any rows?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in the following way if you have an incremental ID column in the table.

What I am suggesting is to take the `MAX` value and break it into `3 parts` and then extract samples from these sets, as the `SAMPLE` clause works on top of the `WHERE`

```
WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT MAX(ID) MAX_ID
    FROM pmaster_numeric
    )
SELECT *
FROM pmaster_numeric
SAMPLE BLOCK(33)
WHERE id < (
        SELECT MAX_ID
        FROM CTE
        ) / 3 

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM pmaster_numeric
SAMPLE BLOCK(33)
WHERE id > (
        SELECT MAX_ID
        FROM CTE
        ) / 3
    AND id < 2 * (
        SELECT MAX_ID
        FROM CTE
        ) / 3

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM pmaster_numeric
SAMPLE BLOCK(33)
WHERE id > 2 * (
        SELECT MAX_ID
        FROM CTE
        ) / 3
    AND id < (
        SELECT MAX_ID
        FROM CTE
        )
```

Comment: I do have an ID column, but I am uncertain as to whether or not it is incremental. Additionally, it does not start at 1, so I am not sure whether or not the WHERE clauses in your query will work the way you intend them to.

Comment: You could do Row_numbering on your table to get to an incremental id, do you have a date field to order the rows on..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select from a table everything that is not in another table, you can use [MINUS](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/minus.php).

```
CREATE TABLE training_sample_1 AS
SELECT *
FROM pmaster_numeric
SAMPLE BLOCK (33, 100);

CREATE TABLE training_sample_2 AS
select *
from
(
  SELECT *
  FROM pmaster_numeric
  MINUS
  select *
  from   training_sample_1
)
SAMPLE BLOCK (33, 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing a trick here, which is to select a single set of data and then split it among multiple target tables using a conditional multitable insert.

Modify your select so that it takes the complete sample that you want, then use a meaningless attribute derived from the data to send each row to a particular destination table.

As long as your sample is repeatable and your discriminating attribute is deterministically based on the data (so not rownum, I would suggest), you'll be all clear.

Also, this single pass method will perform much better on large data sets.

```
create table test0 (col1 number);

insert into test0
select rownum
from dual
connect by level <= 100;

create table test1 (col1 number);

create table test2 (col1 number);

create table test3 (col1 number);


insert all
  when tgt_table=1 then into test1(col1) values(col1)
  when tgt_table=2 then into test2(col1) values(col1)
  when tgt_table=3 then into test3(col1) values(col1)
select test0.col1,
       mod(rownum,3)+1 tgt_table
from   test0 sample(20);

select * from test1;

select * from test2;

select * from test3;
```

See the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/159da/7) for a demo